# Unity UI is blured when centered

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

Today, I am facing problem. I am using the new Unity UI, but when I select that I want to center it, it gets blured. Is there any way to fix it?

[image: screen]

- Version: 2017.2.0f3
- Platform: Windows 10

Comment: I sometimes experience that Unitys UI system behaves a bit odd. Is it still blurry if you make it centered and then add the text afterwards as a new object? So add the text after you set up the parent object.

Comment: @Doh09 Thanks for fast response! I already solved that! But thank you very mutch!

Comment: Glad it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh. I solved it! It is because I have not checked **Pixel Perfect** option in canvas.

[image: screen]